# Chrome Desktop Notifications - larger size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to change chrome desktop HTML Notification size? I am creating one chrome extension in which I need quite large HTML notification. Need Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is having large notifications such a good idea? Think about it.

Answer (score 1):

The height will usually expand for an extra couple of lines of text but the width is not configurable.

You might want to look into the experimental infobar API: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.infobars.html